# how to create configurable product with existing sku

Tags: magento2

I tried creating Configurable product for color the issue is by default it creates its own sku, I want to use the product existing sku to create swatch image product

But when I created the swatch image product for existing sku, automatically it creates new sku, i cannot use the original sku for swatch image product, because of this inventory control is very difficult as original sku will have the inventory which cannot be linked to random sku created.

Is it possible to create swatch image product in Magento 2 with existing sku without changing the sku to any random sku?

Answer (score 0):

Configurable product has no stock quantity. You should still use inventory management on simple products associated with that configurable product and leave the management to the Magento. All simple products should have SKU's that represents some inventory source item.

For example:

Configurable SKU: SOMESKU_CONF;
Simple SKU 1: SOMESKU_1;
Simple SKU 2: SOMESKU_2

Only SOMESKU_1, SOMESKU_2 should have stock quantity.
If your indexing is working as expected SOMESKU_CONF should update it's stock status depending on simple products stock quantity (and status).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Controller;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
class Test extends Action
{
    protected $customerSession;
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $redirectFactory;
    protected $newProduct;
    public function __construct(Context $context, Product $newProduct, \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager)
    {
        $this->newProduct = $newProduct;
        parent::__construct($context);
 
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $product = $this->newProduct;
        $product->setSku('mySku'); // Set your sku here
        $product->setName('Sample Configurable Product'); // Name of Product
        $product->setAttributeSetId(4); // Attribute set id
        $product->setStatus(1); // Status on product enabled/ disabled 1/0
        $product->setWeight(10); // weight of product
        $product->setVisibility(4); // visibilty of product (catalog / search / catalog, search / Not visible individually)
        $product->setTaxClassId(0); // Tax class id
        $product->setTypeId('configurable'); // type of product (simple/virtual/downloadable/configurable)
        $product->setPrice(100); // price of product
        $product->setStockData(array('use_config_manage_stock' => 0, 'manage_stock' => 1, 'is_in_stock' => 1, 'qty' => 999999999));
        $product->save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in the create product screen. Firstly, its important to make sure that the simple products you want to attach have been individually assigned an option of the attribute you want to use beforehand.

Example, you have four t-shirts, each a different color - blue, red, yellow, pink. Each simple product should have color attribute set.

Then - create a configurable product. Enter name, SKU, and Price (set as 0) - and then click "Create Configurations". Follow the prompts to

1. select your attribute (e.g. color)
2. select all the options (e.g. blue, red, yellow, pink)
3. select SKIP for images, price & quantity at this stage
4. select Generate Products if the review screen looks correct so far

**Important** - at this stage, **don't save the product just yet**.
You will have now have a table with your options. For each item, in the Actions column, click SELECT > CHOOSE A DIFFERENT PRODUCT.
[image]

You'll be presented with a list of all products that match that attribute (e.g. all items which have a blue color). Select the correct item. Do that for all products until all the dummy-generated products have been replaced with a simple product.
[image]

**Now you can save the new configurable product**.
[image]